# Upgrade to 18.04 cannot click & drag a file from Nautilus

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, nautilus, drag-and-drop

Basic function = click on a file & while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, drag to a new window (Nautilus/other app etc). Worked through all versions of Ubuntu until 18.04. Now only selects files instead of dragging the first one I wanted to the new location (copy).

In the keyboard shortcuts I can find no reference to a <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *Left click* combo for selection or move.

How to restore this basic functionality?

Comment: SOLVED. In Nautilus (File Manager) Files, Preferences, Experimental - DO NOT USE this option if you want to copy/paste/drag as previously. Hahhhhaaaaa.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

In Nautilus (File Manager) Files, Preferences, Experimental - DO NOT USE this option if you want to copy/paste/drag as previously.
[image]